# dovecot-antispam error storing mail

Tags: linux, email, dovecot, dspam

I've got a server running dovecot with the dovecot-antispam plugin.  These are sourced from the Standard Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.

I know mail is not supposed to be moved into a mailbox of type 'unsure'.  The server should refuse this action.  What actually happens though is that the imap process throws an error and dies:

```
Aug 12 17:53:07 255c7fc2d2f0 imap: antispam: mailbox_is_unsure(Review-Classification): 1
Aug 12 17:53:07 255c7fc2d2f0 dovecot: imap(user@example.com): Panic: file mail-storage.c: line 2141 (mailbox_copy): assertion failed: (!ctx->unfinished)
Aug 12 17:53:07 255c7fc2d2f0 dovecot: imap(user@example.com): Error: Raw backtrace: /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5e271) [0x7f718e7dd271] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5e34e) [0x7f718e7dd34e] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(i_fatal+0) [0x7f718e798a9e] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-storage.so.0(+0x7196f) [0x7f718eab896f] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-storage.so.0(mailbox_move+0x15) [0x7f718eab8985] -> dovecot/imap(+0xded5) [0x7f718ef84ed5] -> dovecot/imap(command_exec+0x3c) [0x7f718ef8f6dc] -> dovecot/imap(+0x176cf) [0x7f718ef8e6cf] -> dovecot/imap(+0x17785) [0x7f718ef8e785] -> dovecot/imap(client_handle_input+0x125) [0x7f718ef8eaa5] -> dovecot/imap(client_input+0x75) [0x7f718ef8ee35] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_call_io+0x27) [0x7f718e7ed247] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_handler_run+0xd7) [0x7f718e7edfd7] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_run+0x38) [0x7f718e7ecde8] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(master_service_run+0x13) [0x7f718e79dc93] -> dovecot/imap(main+0x2c4) [0x7f718ef832f4] -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f718e3dbec5] -> dovecot/imap(+0xc460) [0x7f718ef83460]
Aug 12 17:53:07 255c7fc2d2f0 dovecot: imap(user@example.com): Fatal: master: service(imap): child 58 killed with signal 6 (core dumped)
```

So, the primary issue is that I want to figure out how to get my server to handle this more gracefully, and refuse the move properly without just having the process die.  I'm not sure how to approach this.  I can provide configuration as required, but presumably this isn't just a configuration issue.  I've installed the dovecot-dbg package, but that doesn't seem to improve the logged stacktrace much.

A secondary issue is that Thunderbird's handling of this is pretty nasty also.  The message disappears from display and the mail folder it's being moved from, and doesn't appear in the target folder.  Thunderbird continually tries and fails to move the message on the server.  The only way I know to break this pattern is to temporarily remove the target folder from the antispam_unsure directive in dovecot, which is cumbersome for working out the issue.  Any suggestions here are welcome, but this is a secondary concern.

Edit:

After some help from IRC and http://www.dovecot.org/bugreport.html I figured out how to get a stacktrace (Have docker set `ulimit -c unlimited` before starting dovecot, and set /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern from outside the container ... would be nice if that was container specific).  So, I now have a core file and a stacktrace:

```
#0  0x00007f5dd5394cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
        resultvar = 0
        pid = 61
        selftid = 61
#1  0x00007f5dd53980d8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
        save_stage = 2
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0x800, sa_sigaction = 0x800}, sa_mask = {__val = {140041026109520, 178, 140041026077952, 512, 
              140040990095251, 140041026077952, 140041026077952, 512, 140040990087565, 140734823456136, 140040990231826, 140041026077952, 140734823456040, 0, 
              140040990231929, 140041026077952}}, sa_flags = -713567062, sa_restorer = 0x7fff6128dd01}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
#2  0x00007f5dd5781298 in default_fatal_finish (type=<optimized out>, status=status@entry=0) at failures.c:192
        backtrace = 0x7f5dd79d0538 "/usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5e271) [0x7f5dd5781271] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5e34e) [0x7f5dd578134e] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(i_fatal+0) [0x7f5dd573ca9e] -> /usr/lib/d"...
#3  0x00007f5dd578134e in i_internal_fatal_handler (ctx=0x7fff6128dd70, format=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at failures.c:653
        status = 0
#4  0x00007f5dd573ca9e in i_panic (format=format@entry=0x7f5dd5ab1e68 "file %s: line %d (%s): assertion failed: (%s)") at failures.c:264
        ctx = {type = LOG_TYPE_PANIC, exit_status = 0, timestamp = 0x0}
        args = {{gp_offset = 40, fp_offset = 48, overflow_arg_area = 0x7fff6128de60, reg_save_area = 0x7fff6128dda0}}
#5  0x00007f5dd5a5c96f in mailbox_copy (_ctx=<optimized out>, mail=mail@entry=0x7f5dd79ffbc0) at mail-storage.c:2141
        ctx = 0x7f5dd7a043e0
        t = 0x7f5dd79fdf00
        keywords = 0x0
        pvt_flags = 0
        real_mail = <optimized out>
        ret = -1
        __FUNCTION__ = "mailbox_copy"
#6  0x00007f5dd5a5c985 in mailbox_move (_ctx=<optimized out>, mail=0x7f5dd79ffbc0) at mail-storage.c:2153
        ctx = 0x7f5dd7a043e0
#7  0x00007f5dd5f28ed5 in fetch_and_copy (copy_count_r=<synthetic pointer>, src_uidset_r=<synthetic pointer>, search_args=<optimized out>, 
    src_trans_r=0x7fff6128df18, t=<optimized out>, move=true, client=0x7f5dd79ee440) at cmd-copy.c:67
        search_ctx = 0x7f5dd79ff920
        src_trans = 0x7f5dd79fec10
        srcset_ctx = {str = 0x7f5dd79d0350, first_uid = 0, last_uid = 4294967295}
        ret = 1
        save_ctx = 0x0
        mail = 0x7f5dd79ffbc0
        copy_count = 1
        src_uidset = 0x7f5dd79d0350
#8  cmd_copy_full (cmd=0x7f5dd79eee70, move=<optimized out>) at cmd-copy.c:123
        client = 0x7f5dd79ee440
        dest_storage = <optimized out>
        destbox = 0x7f5dd79f8d10
        t = 0x7f5dd79fdf00
        src_trans = 0x7f5dd573d029 <t_pop_check+9>
        search_args = 0x7f5dd79f73a0
        messageset = 0x7f5dd79dbc10 "76"
        mailbox = 0x7f5dd79dbc18 "Review-Classification"
        src_uidset = <optimized out>
        sync_flags = (unknown: 0)
        imap_flags = (unknown: 0)
        changes = {pool = 0x7f5dd79d0350, uid_validity = 0, saved_uids = {arr = {buffer = 0x1, element_size = 140040986301132}, v = 0x1, v_modifiable = 0x1}, 
          ignored_modseq_changes = 3617438728, changed = 93, no_read_perm = 127}
        msg = <optimized out>
        ret = <optimized out>
        __FUNCTION__ = "cmd_copy_full"
#9  0x00007f5dd5f336dc in command_exec (cmd=0x7f5dd79eee70) at imap-commands.c:158
        hook = 0x7f5dd79d90d0
        ret = <optimized out>
#10 0x00007f5dd5f326cf in client_command_input (cmd=0x7f5dd79eee70) at imap-client.c:780
        client = 0x7f5dd79ee440
        command = <optimized out>
        __FUNCTION__ = "client_command_input"
#11 0x00007f5dd5f32785 in client_command_input (cmd=0x7f5dd79eee70) at imap-client.c:841
        client = 0x7f5dd79ee440
        command = <optimized out>
        __FUNCTION__ = "client_command_input"
#12 0x00007f5dd5f32aa5 in client_handle_next_command (remove_io_r=<synthetic pointer>, client=0x7f5dd79ee440) at imap-client.c:879
No locals.
#13 client_handle_input (client=client@entry=0x7f5dd79ee440) at imap-client.c:891
        _data_stack_cur_id = 3
        remove_io = false
        handled_commands = false
        __FUNCTION__ = "client_handle_input"
#14 0x00007f5dd5f32e35 in client_input (client=0x7f5dd79ee440) at imap-client.c:933
        cmd = 0x7f5dd79e5ae0
        output = 0x7f5dd79eeca0
        bytes = 39
        __FUNCTION__ = "client_input"
#15 0x00007f5dd5791247 in io_loop_call_io (io=0x7f5dd79eed90) at ioloop.c:388
        ioloop = 0x7f5dd79d8720
        t_id = 2
#16 0x00007f5dd5791fd7 in io_loop_handler_run (ioloop=ioloop@entry=0x7f5dd79d8720) at ioloop-epoll.c:220
        ctx = 0x7f5dd79d93b0
        list = 0x7f5dd79dade0
        io = <optimized out>
        tv = {tv_sec = 1799, tv_usec = 999178}
        events_count = <optimized out>
        msecs = <optimized out>
        ret = 1
        i = 0
        call = <optimized out>
        __FUNCTION__ = "io_loop_handler_run"
#17 0x00007f5dd5790de8 in io_loop_run (ioloop=0x7f5dd79d8720) at ioloop.c:412
        __FUNCTION__ = "io_loop_run"
#18 0x00007f5dd5741c93 in master_service_run (service=0x7f5dd79d85b0, callback=<optimized out>) at master-service.c:566
No locals.
#19 0x00007f5dd5f272f4 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7f5dd79d8390) at main.c:400
        set_roots = {0x7f5dd614aa00 <imap_setting_parser_info>, 0x0}
        login_set = {auth_socket_path = 0x7f5dd79d0048 "\001", postlogin_socket_path = 0x0, postlogin_timeout_secs = 60, 
          callback = 0x7f5dd5f3c0f0 <login_client_connected>, failure_callback = 0x7f5dd5f3be20 <login_client_failed>, request_auth_token = 1}
        service_flags = <optimized out>
        storage_service_flags = <optimized out>
        username = 0x0
        c = <optimized out>
```

- Ubuntu 14.04.3
- dovecot-imapd 1:2.2.9-1ubuntu2
- dovecot-antispam 2.0+20130822-2build1

Comment: All program fails are a case for the bugtracker or the mailinglist of the projects. This should never happen in stable software.

Comment: Ï've sent this to the dovecot mailing list.  No response so far.